# How to politely remind somebody of a meeting we had a few days ago?

Tags: email, letter

The person in question is a superior and I was wondering how to start the email I am writing to this person with a reminder of that meeting.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions we can answer.

Comment: I am sorry about that, can you please tell me where this would be an appropriate question?

Comment: You could try [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). I'm sure they have their own requirements, but this seems like an issue they'd handle. Alternately, if this is an issue with English as a second language, you could try [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @NeilFein, should I delete the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business correspondence is just one of the subjects discussed at [The Workspace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), a Stack Exchange forum for career and work related subjects.

Specific to your question...
Do you have a real-business reason to contact this superior or are you just trying to demonstrate that your willing to waste both of your work time, in the hopes of improving your visibility (and therefore your career) within the company?

When dealing with people who have authority, always demonstrate professionalism until they invite you into a more relaxed correspondense.  There doesn't have to be a critical business emergency to justify every short note, but there should at least be a reason for your writing.  If you received any take-away assignments from that previous meeting then informing your superior that those tasks are complete is an excellent excuse to write.

Once you have a reason for writing, it is good practice to remind the receiver of who you are, especially if this is your first time writing to them.  So right after you tell them the purpose of the correspondense, thank them for something they said directly to you during the previous meeting.  If no such statement is available, then mention the date, time and subject of the meeting and move on to your reason for writing.  Then next time you are in a meeting with the recipient, make sure to say something memorable so that you can use it in your next correspondense.

Comment: Nope, he wanted me to mail him about the questions I asked him when we met. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @PriyathamKattakinda, "Mail me about the questions which you asked" is both a take-away assignment and a slight invitation to a more open dialogue.  I had imagined your scenario very differently from what it now seems to have been.  I imagined that you and several dozen other co-workers were invited to a meeting with someone who is several levels higher than you in the corporate heirachy.  In such a case, continuing correspondence would be acceptable only under the conditions I described above.  In any Stack Exchange forum, it is good practice to provide relevent details in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

(I am assuming you actually *had* the meeting - and want to refer to it, in the email)

[Boss]

Thanks for meeting with me on Wednesday. Recall that I was the [engineer] who had many questions about [issue].

You asked me to send a summary email with the questions, so you could more easily address them. Here they are:

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...

Thanks in advance for giving this some attention. It will really help me to [complete my job better or more quickly] - and will go a long way towards [resolving a specific issue or improving a specific situation - name it here]

[employee]

Comment: I think my question was not clear, the meeting was the first time I met the person, so I have to remind him of me too.